# XML generation using PHP function

Tags: php, xml, function

1. I am creating an Android app for website.
2. I Want to create an XML File for Android App using PHP.
3. I already have a Bunch of data(Paragraphs & text) in mysql database
   which we have  already used for displaying in their website.
4. Now what i need to do is To use the same data which they Used for
   website for generating XML File.
5. The problem is when i bound to create an XML File it starts generating Error Because of invalid XML Complaint characters.What appears Complaint in Browser for website is not complaint in XML.

   Q1. Is it Possible to Generate XML file with datas which are already in database.

   Q2. Is it Possible to make Characters like “ - (left double quotation mark),” - (right double quotation mark), ‘ - (left single quotation mark), ’-(right single quotation mark), – - (Its not hyphen its en Dash) in to html through PHP.

Comment: Yes, both of them are possible. Most of RSS feeds are built that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA), eg

```
<node><![CDATA[<?php echo $someHtml ?>]]></node>
```

If you're using DOM to generate your XML, use [`DOMDocument::createCDATASection()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php)

Comment: The Above method is not working when i pull datas from db Recordset

Comment: @user1093513 We'd appreciate it, if you'd be able to post some segment of your code here.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Web Service For That Like Soap-server the soap server genarates xml file for the android and iphone app and for any character issue you can use  cdata tag like

```
<![CDATA[ $variablename ]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use special characters in XML, this is a question of entities and if they are defined. There are some sources for information about that:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-entities/
http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/